# FileWriter to write to user desktop in Java, rather than server desktop

Tags: java, jsp, path, filewriter

As part of a search application, I want the user to be able to download a report showing the results in a CSV file. I have the following method:

```
public void downloadCustomerResults(String customer) {
        String output = "";
        output += produceCustomerID(customer);
        output += produceCustomerAddress(customer);
        output += produceCustomerContactDetails(customer);
        output += produceOrderHeader(customer);
        output += producePayments(customer);

        //  Writes to server desktop, not user desktop.
        try {
            Writer fileWriter = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\SAR" + customer + "C.csv");
            fileWriter.write(output);
            fileWriter.flush();
            fileWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This downloads the file to the desktop of the machine running the server, not the user's desktop (accessing the app via JSP's on Tomcat). How would I change the file path string to make this download to the users' desktop? Or would I have to pass the file to the JSP for the user to download via their browser?

Thanks.

Comment: The data needs to pass through the internet. There's no remote file path to your computer that the server could access. That's why you always get a file download option, instead of finding mysterious files on your desktop.

Comment: That makes sense, so I'm guessing that I'm better writing the file to a dedicated folder within the app, that the web page can then retrieve?

Comment: You don't need to use a file at all. You can write the data to the user directly, then they just get the download option and can save it whereever they want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer I found was to use the JavaScript package FileSaver.js.
This accepts a blob created from a string, and then saves it with a filename of your choice to the browsers preferred download folder.

I managed to pass the string from Java to JavaScript, and then pass it through FileSaver.js in the .JSP page.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: The server has no means of accessing the client's filesystem.

Longer answer: You might either provide a service for the client to download the file (e.g. a webservice accessible through a URI, like @Kayaman mentioned) or the client provides you a service to write the file (e.g. a remote file system, an FTP server etc.). For the latter there *might* be libraries providing a special `java.nio.FileSystem` extension.

You may also provide an application running on the client to receive the file. This client application will then have acces to the client's file systems (unless it lacks the access rights, of course).